# Trying To Clean Up My PHP Error Logs

Tags: php, code-cleanup

I know that you're supposed to define PHP variables so that you don't clog up your error log with undefined variables, but my logs are still getting filled with unnecessary information.

For instance...

```
[28-Jan-2013 16:45:42 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: site in C:\Sites\FLCBranson.org\freedownloads.php on line 34
```

My PHP code has `$site` defined, but I do want to have option to override it...

```
// it's a good idea to define the variable first and then make changes as necessary (that way you don't fill up your logs with worthless errors)
$site = "flc";
// overrides the domain (useful for IP addresses)
if ($_GET["site"]) $site = $_GET["site"];
```

So, I have a lot of that type of issue.  Then I have a bunch of these pesky errors...

```
[28-Jan-2013 16:45:42 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 3 in C:\Sites\FLCBranson.org\listseries.php on line 264
[28-Jan-2013 16:45:42 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 4 in C:\Sites\FLCBranson.org\listseries.php on line 265
[28-Jan-2013 16:45:42 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 5 in C:\Sites\FLCBranson.org\listseries.php on line 266
```

I have an array that is populated with various bits of content.  If something is in one of the slots, then I want to do something with it...

```
// explode() takes a string of text ($item->title in this case) and creates an array comprised of parts of the text separated by the separator (- in this case)
$title = explode(" - ", $sermontitle);
// sets the sermon title variable
$sermontitle = $title[0];
if ($title[1]) $sermontitle = $sermontitle . " - " . $title[1];
if ($title[2]) $sermontitle = $sermontitle . "<br>" . $title[2];
if ($title[3]) $sermontitle = $sermontitle . " - " . $title[3];
if ($title[4]) $sermontitle = $sermontitle . " - " . $title[4];
if ($title[5]) $sermontitle = $sermontitle . " - " . $title[5];
```

So, what am I doing incorrectly?  I define my variable.  Then I only make changes to the variable if certain conditions are met.  I thought that was the appropriate way of doing it.

Edit...

I found another odd instance...

```
[28-Jan-2013 20:07:05 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: broadcast in C:\Sites\FLCBranson.org\flconlineservices.php on line 242
```

It seems that `if (file_exists($golive) || ($broadcast == "live")` isn't enough.  Do I need to do `if (file_exists($golive) || (isset($broadcast) && $broadcast == "live"))`?  That seems like a lot of code to perform a simple comparison.

Edit 2...

So, I'm starting to understand why `isset()` is required, but here's something that I don't get.  I have some code pulling information from a database and I have `if ($row["Sarasota"])` but the error log doesn't show a single thing for that.  Why wouldn't `isset()` be required there if it is required for `if ($title[5])`?  The only difference I can see is the quoted word "Sarasota" as opposed to the unquoted numeric 5.

Comment: you're assuming that explode() will always produce 6 entries. if it doesn't (as it is for you), you only get entries 0->2, leaving 3-5 undefined and you get those warnings. you need to check each individual array element to see if it eixsts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ($_GET["site"])
```

must be

```
if (isset($_GET["site"]))
```

And also for the $title things you should use isset:

```
if (isset($title[1])) [...]
```

Comment: I choose this as the accepted answer because it notes that you can use `isset()` for both `$_GET[]` and `$variable`.

Comment: It seems that, after adding all these `isset()`s, my pages are taking longer to load.  It seems logical, though, as now the PHP engine is doing twice the work.  Do others experience this, as well?

Comment: @doubleJ isset() is not the reason your application is slower, search somewhere else. You can easily execute isset 10 million times in a second, demo here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/160d670bdf7ec6e9dca408d9a75034e4ee639056 so that is definitely not the reason your application is slower.

Comment: Is there some kind of a performance analyzer that I could try out?  There are a couple pages, in particular, that are just really slow to load.  Edit...Man, it just took 22 seconds to change to a page after clicking the link (not load the page, change to the page).

Comment: Apparently, the load times are being caused by geolocation detection.  I've been using the same service for several months, without issue.  I guess there is something up with it.

Answer (score 3):

Use isset to avoid these notice:

```
if (isset($title[1]) && $title[1]) $sermontitle = $sermontitle . " - " . $title[1];
if (isset($title[2]) && $title[2]) $sermontitle = $sermontitle . "<br>" . $title[2];
if (isset($title[3]) && $title[3]) $sermontitle = $sermontitle . " - " . $title[3];
if (isset($title[4]) && $title[4]) $sermontitle = $sermontitle . " - " . $title[4];
if (isset($title[5]) && $title[5]) $sermontitle = $sermontitle . " - " . $title[5];
```

Comment: What is the purpose for the extra `&& $title[x]` bit?  I noticed that it works without it and no one else added it.

Comment: @doubleJ because ´isset´ only test if the key exists, not if a value is really inside.

Answer (score 3):

A common way to write a **default value** is by using the ternary operator `? :` like so:

```
$site = isset($_GET["site"]) ? $_GET["site"] : null; // null is the default value
```

For arrays I would recommend using the `count` function rather than `isset`. This reinforces the reader's understanding that you're dealing with an array.

`isset` is more comment used in associative arrays (like `$_GET`) so you might expect other keys that are not necessarily numeric.

Comment: It seems like that this ternary operator way could get unnecessarily complex.  For instance, I commonly set a variable and then have 3, 4, or 5 replacements for that variable.  It does seem to be straight-forward for a single if/then, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a solution that encompasses isset's error handling, by using !empty

```
if(!empty($_GET['site']))
```

Comment: While this is a good point (and I have used `!empty()` in other areas), it's worth noting that `!empty()` and `isset()` can produce different results, depending on how the variable is initially set.  I just saw on the [PHP type comparisons page](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) that `$x = null;` is true for `!empty($x)` and false for `isset($x)`